# Cerrar menú clickeando afuera del mismo

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un menú que se abre y se cierra con un toggle pero me solicitaron que también se tiene que cerrar cuando clickeas afuera del menú cuando está abierto. ¿Cómo puedo agregarle esta última función?

No sé si es importante aclarar que cuando se carga el documento primero corre

```
$(".participant-list").hide()
```

Estuve probando cosas sin éxito. Les dejo el html y el js abajo.

```
<div>
  <button class="participant flex mr-[15px] text-[15px] mb-[30px]">
    Participant
    <img
      class="self-center ml-[15px]"
      src="./assets/img/filter-button-arrow.svg"
      alt=""
    />
  </button>
  <div
    class="participant-list participant-filter flex flex-col justify-center px-[20px] w-[142px] h-[100px] rounded-md"
  >
    <div class="flex checkbox items-center mb-4">
      <input
        id="ind"
        rel="Individual"
        type="checkbox"
        value=""
        onchange="change()"
        class="models accent-[#8400FF] w-4 h-4"
      />
      <label for="ind" class="ml-2 text-[13px]">Individual</label>
    </div>
    <div class="flex checkbox items-center">
      <input
        id="org"
        rel="Organization"
        type="checkbox"
        value=""
        onchange="change()"
        class="models accent-[#8400FF] w-4 h-4"
      />
      <label for="org" class="ml-2 text-[13px]">Organization</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".participant").click(function () {
    $(".participant-list").toggle()
  })
```

Comment: Con el código que pusiste, no es posible ayudarte, ni siquiera a hacer pruebas

Comment: que me esta faltando?

Comment: Como tu código es HTML + JS, puedes agregar un [repro] en la pregunta como snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`).

Comment: Sugerencia: cuando lances una pregunta y encuentres la respuesta o te des cuenta si la pregunta tuvo algún error tipográfico, evita eliminarla, hay una enorme cantidad de usuarios que pueden pasar por lo mismo y serías el héroe de todos ellos al darles una luz con su caso. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente debes crear otra función para poder hacer toggle fuera del menú.

```javascript
$("body").click(function () {
   $(".participant-list").toggle()
})
```

Además, no es necesario agregar `$(".participant-list").hide()`, lo puedes hacer con CSS `display: none;` para que no se vea al cargar el documento.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Intenta con lo siguiente en tu JS.

//El script lo modifiqué, para que al detectar el evento de clic sobre el botón, verifique si tu lista de opciones se encuentra visible, ocultándola o viceversa.



    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".participant-list").hide();
    })
    $(".participant").click(function () {
     if (!$(".participant-list").is(":hidden")) {
       $(".participant-list").hide()
      }
    else{
     $(".participant-list").toggle();
        
    }
      })

  //En esta sección, se detecta el evento de clic, pero sobre el body; sin embargo, aquí válido si la lista de opciones está presente en el body, por medio de un target length, si encuentra el elemento, lo oculta.

    $("body").click(function(ev) {
      var target = $(ev.target);
    if(target.not('.participant').length){
               $(".participant-list").hide();
            }
    });
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      <button class="participant flex mr-[15px] text-[15px] mb-[30px]">
         Participant
          <img
             class="self-center ml-[15px]"
             src="./assets/img/filter-button-arrow.svg"
             alt=""
          />
      </button>
      <div
         class="participant-list participant-filter flex flex-col justify-center px-[20px] w-[142px] h-[100px] rounded-md">
         <div class="flex checkbox items-center mb-4">
                  <input
                    id="ind"
                    rel="Individual"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value=""
                    onchange="change()"
                    class="models accent-[#8400FF] w-4 h-4"
                  />
                  <label for="ind" class="ml-2 text-[13px]">Individual</label>
          </div>
          <div class="flex checkbox items-center">
                  <input
                    id="org"
                    rel="Organization"
                    type="checkbox"
                    value=""
                    onchange="change()"
                    class="models accent-[#8400FF] w-4 h-4"
                  />
                  <label for="org" class="ml-2 text-[13px]">Organization</label>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer].